# Python: How do I display a timer in a terminal

Tags: python, timer

I'm new to python programming and using ubuntu to do so. In a program I have done I used a delay of 1 minute until it executes the code again. How can I program a timer to be displayed in the terminal based on the value of the delayed time? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Do you mean that you want the terminal to display the current time when the script executes? Or do you want to display the time that the program has been running for. What you mean by delayed time is really open to interpretation. It would also help greatly if you would provide some code for us to look over and get a better feel for what you mean.

Comment: What I mean id that if the delay() is of 60 seconds, I want a countdown to be displayed, like a stop watch... hour:min:sec

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way is as follows.

```
import time
import sys

for remaining in range(10, 0, -1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining)) 
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write("\rComplete!            \n")
```

`"\r"` returns the text cursor to the beginning of the line, so that you can overwrite what you're previously written. Because typically output isn't written until a newline (`"\n"`), you need to manually `.flush()` the output stream.

Because the line isn't being cleared, we need to ensure that each new line of output is long enough to cover up the existing line.

The `curses` module has tools for more advanced terminal output, but is more complicated to use.

Comment: for older versions of python, replace the line :

sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))

with 

sys.stdout.write("{0} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))